# Redesigning an excel table through functions/makros?

Tags: excel

I have to work with a large excel sheet that I get as our accounting program output. My job is to make it presentable for the CEO.

I made macros that get me this far but it's still not in the shape he wants it. As it is a very large table I would be very happy to find a way to automate it because it takes me a long time to make it presentable by hand.

The job has some logic to it so I hope someone has an idea how this could be solved.

What I have got so far:

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6zJJ.jpg)

And this is what I want it to be - separated by company name, and summed by saldo.

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWrjY.jpg)

Comment: Pivot tables are the way to go. Use partner, invoice, date & deadline as rows and then summarise debit, credit and saldo.

Comment: plus, there's something strange going on with Company A. Should have paid their invoices a long time ago and have a large negative debit transaction...

Comment: how about Subtotals or pivtotables?

Answer (score 0):

Your `picture1` table is a good start. From that data source create a PivotTable. Put in `rows` of PivotTable every column name except `SALDO`, which you should put in values field. Now select PivotTable=>go to `Design` tab=>`Report Layout`=>`Show in Tabular Form`. After you changed layout to tabular, remove all `Subtotals` except Company Subtotal. If everything done correctly, you should have something similar to picture below.[image]